# Do I have this LEFT JOIN right?

Tags: sql, ms-access, join, left-join, outer-join

I need to find the total number of customers created after a given date that haven't yet ordered.

I have two tables:

```
| customers           |    // There's more to this but this is all
+----+------+---------+    // you need to answer this question
| ID | Name | Created |
+----+------+---------+

| orders           |    // There's more to this but this is all
+----+-------------+    // you need to answer this question
| ID | customer_id |
+----+-------------+
```

I need to find the total number of customers created after a given date that haven't yet ordered.

This is what I did:

```
SELECT Count(*)
FROM customers
LEFT JOIN orders ON customers.ID = orders.customer_id
WHERE customers.Created > #arbitrary date#
AND orders.ID Is Null;
```

I feel certain this is right, however it doesn't seem to be producing the right results. By that I mean my boss is looking at the results and telling me that from experience the numbers of new customer signups who aren't ordering are far more than what this query is producing.

So am I doing this right? If I am, I clearly need to look at what else could be causing the problem. Thanks.

**EDIT 1**

A comment below suggested that the `orders.id` is not nullable. This may be the case, however I get the same results if I check if `orders.customer_id Is Null`.

**EDIT 2**

I didn't want to overcomplicate things but it might be useful if you know that I'm doing this in an Access database so I can't use all the goodies that standard SQL allows. (I've edited the tags)

Comment: I don't see any error. Ask your boss from where come his experience instead :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your boss must tell you what he considered 'good values'.

Maybe he used to have a report with others filter to count this customer. Maybe you have to check a price somewhere in orders table, and consider not a real orders if price = 0.

With the information you give us, your query is absolutely right, maybe I will add something :

```
SELECT Count(DISTINCT customers.ID)
FROM customers
    LEFT JOIN orders 
        ON customers.ID = orders.customer_id
WHERE customers.Created > #arbitrary date#
AND orders.ID Is Null;
```

For easier maintenance and understanding (the query should be a little slower, but not that much)

Comment: He may prefer `COUNT(*) AS Count_Customers_Without_Orders`

Comment: Are you aware that Access does not support `COUNT(DISTINCT <col>)`?

Answer (score 1):

I'm wondering if their is a subtle bug-waiting-to-happen in your code.

The spec states, "find the total number of customers". By joining to the `orders` table you are actually counting on the join. Of course, in the case of customers with no orders you are indeed counting customers. However, for customers with orders you would be counting their orders.

I'd prefer a query construct that reflected the count on the customers so that I (or indeed a more casual user) could switch the antijoin to a semijoin and obtain the expected results (with your construct they would obtain a misleading count) e.g.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM customers
 WHERE customers.Created > #specific date#
       AND NOT EXISTS (
                       SELECT *
                         FROM orders
                        WHERE orders.customer_id = customers.ID
                      );
```

As for the accepted answer, I offer this "For easier maintenance and understanding" (the query may be a little slower but hopefully not by much)."

Comment: Thanks @onedaywhen. I think your answer is spot on and this is what I did at first. It was the speed issue that lead me to use the left join instead. However, it isn't dramatically faster, both are very slow so I may go back to doing it this way anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps somewhere your code allows orders to be recorded for customers (but not completed).
You can count customers that have ordered only orders with 0 amount.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM
  ( SELECT customers.id
    FROM customers
      INNER JOIN orders ON customers.ID = orders.customer_id
    WHERE customers.Created > #arbitrary date# 
    GROUP BY customers.id
    HAVING COUNT(IIF(orders.amount > 0, 1, NULL)) = 0  
  ) AS grp
```

Access has not `CASE` statement but it has an `IIF()` function.

And `INNER JOIN` is required instead of `JOIN`.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately if I try this it says there is a syntax error in my `FROM` clause. I suspect this is because I'm trying this in MS Access which is a pile of turd.

Comment: @MrMisterMan: Updated query for Ms-Access.

Comment: @ypercube Still no luck I'm afraid. It doesn't help that MS Access' error messages provide no clue as to what is wrong. I appreciate your help though.

Comment: @MrMisterMan: That `orders.amount` was a guess. I suppose you have some field that has such information. I've tested the above. I don't understand why it doesn't work in your machine.

Comment: @ypercube I replaced `orders.amount` with the table's equivalent which was `customers.Total` but it didn't work. I'm sure I'm messing something up because I don't doubt that your code is fine. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: In Access's default SQL dialect, you can't use round brackets for the derived table subselect. To work in Access SQL 89 mode, the FROM should be `FROM [SELECT customers.id....]. As grp`. Note the square brackets and the trailing period on the closing bracket. If you need square brackets inside the subselect, you're out of luck...

Answer (score -1):

No this is not right.

Try this instead:

```
SELECT
SUM(CASE WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM orders WHERE customers.ID = orders.customer_id) = 0 
  THEN 1
  ELSE 0
END) 
FROM customers
WHERE customers.Created > #arbitrary date#
```

Comment: @David-W-Fenton I think he might have provided this answer before I clarified it was Access specific.

Answer (score -1):

have a look at [this website](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html), it explains all the differences between the sql joins

Comment: The join in question is an antijoin but the linked articles does not mention this and instead uses a picture/example better suited to the `EXCEPT` relational operator (in SQL: `SELECT * FROM TableA EXCEPT SELECT * FROM TableB;`).

Comment: i linked to it to show the set theory behind the different joins, i'm sure it would help most people in a similar problem where they are trying to work out what parts of each table come out in the result of a join.